# XCode's memory profile tools can't detect this kind of retain cycle?

Tags: ios, xcode, retain-cycle

I make a retain cycle , but in profiling , the tools seems can't find this obivious retain cycle

first , the ViewController will retain the SubViewController as property subVC, and be set as the delegate of SubViewController.

```
@interface ViewController ()<TestDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIViewController* subVC;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"ViewController dealloc");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    SubViewController* subVC = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
    subVC.delegate = self;
    self.subVC = subVC;
    [self presentViewController:subVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)didSelect
{

}
@end
```

And in the SubViewController, the delegate is been set as the strong property to retain the delegate

```
@protocol TestDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)didSelect;
@end

@interface SubViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,strong) id<TestDelegate> delegate;
@end

@interface SubViewController ()

@end

@implementation SubViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"SubViewController dealloc");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

OK , Now the tools seems working only if i switch  between the panel between the All Heap & Leak Checks. And If i dont switch in them . the retain cycle will never gonna be found.
[image]